# Strange output in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Can someone explain why I get this strange output when running this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def x_y():
    return np.random.randint(9999, size=1000), np.random.randint(9999, size=1000)
plt.plot(x_y())
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image: Output of the program]

Answer (score 1):

Your data is a tuple of two *1000 length* arrays.

```
def x_y():
    return np.random.randint(9999, size=1000), np.random.randint(9999, size=1000)
xy = x_y()
print(len(xy))
# > 2
print(xy[0].shape)
# > (1000,)
```

Let's read [pyplot's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot):

> plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1

Thus pyplot will plot a line between `(0, xy[0][i])` and `(1, xy[1][i])`, **for i in range(1000)**.

You probably try to do this:

```
plt.plot(*x_y())
```

This time, it will plot 1000 points joined by lines: `(xy[0][i], xy[1][i])` **for i in range 1000**.

[image: Pyplot]

Yet, the lines don't represent anything here. Therefore you probably want to see individual points:

```
plt.scatter(*x_y())
```

[image: Scatter]

Answer (score 0):

Your function `x_y` is returning a tuple, assigning each element to a variable gives the correct output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def x_y():
    return np.random.randint(9999, size=1000), np.random.randint(9999, size=1000)
x, y = x_y()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]